# How do I rotate a Path around a central point of the Path?

Tags: react-native, animation, svg, react-native-reanimated, skia

I have the following the code which rotates a shape in RN Skia. I am wondering how I can rotate the shape around the central point of the shape, rather than around the point in the screenshot below.

[image]

```
import {
  Path,
  Skia,
  useClockValue,
  useComputedValue,
  Canvas,
  vec

} from '@shopify/react-native-skia'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'

import PathCommands from '../PathCommands'

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
const c = vec(width / 2, height / 2)

export const Headspace = () => {
  const clock = useClockValue()
  useEffect(() => {
    clock.start()
  }, [])

  const path = useComputedValue(() => {
    const p = Skia.Path.Make()

    for (const command of PathCommands.commands) {
      p[command.type](...command.args)
    }

    const m = Skia.Matrix()
    m.translate(c.x, c.y)
    m.rotate(clock.current / 2000)
    p.transform(m)

    return p
  }, [clock])

  return (
    <Canvas style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Path
        path={path}
        style='stroke'
        strokeWidth={1}
        antiAlias
      />
    </Canvas>
  )
}
```

The SVG Path Notation for the shape is listed below, if that is relevant. It works out to ~173 units width and ~172 units height.

```
M154.031 57.526l-.065.327.277.185c11.309 7.571 16.908 17.778 16.908 27.93 0 10.153-5.599 20.359-16.908 27.93l-.277.186.065.327c2.642 13.35-.616 24.525-7.794 31.703-7.178 7.178-18.353 10.436-31.704 7.794l-.327-.065-.185.277c-7.571 11.31-17.778 16.909-27.93 16.909-10.153 0-20.36-5.599-27.93-16.909l-.186-.277-.327.065c-13.35 2.642-24.526-.616-31.704-7.794-7.177-7.178-10.435-18.353-7.793-31.703l.064-.327-.277-.186C6.63 106.327 1.03 96.121 1.03 85.968c0-10.152 5.599-20.359 16.908-27.93l.277-.185-.064-.327c-2.642-13.35.616-24.526 7.794-31.704 7.178-7.178 18.352-10.436 31.703-7.794l.327.065.186-.277C65.735 6.506 75.942.908 86.094.908c10.151 0 20.356 5.599 27.927 16.908l.185.277.327-.065c13.351-2.642 24.526.616 31.704 7.794 7.178 7.178 10.436 18.353 7.794 31.704z
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. To rotate, translate to the center point of your path. Then perform the rotation, as you are doing, and translate back to the original position. From what I see, you're missing the last step. Also make sure the first translate is actually to the center of your path.

Assuming **center** is the center of your path:

```js
const matrix = Skia.Matrix();
matrix.translate(center.x, center.y)
matrix.rotate(clock.current / 2000)
matrix.translate(-center.x, -center.y);
path.transform(matrix);
```